# Структуризация управлением определёнными объектами

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь реализовать простую систему инвентаря.

Есть базовый абстрактный класс **Item**, который требует переопределение **getName()**, **getType()**.

```
class Item
{
public:
    virtual string getName() = 0;
    virtual ItemType getType() = 0;
};
```

Так-же от него наследуются классы различных предметов

```
class SymCard : public Item
{
public: 
    SymCard(int number);
    int getNumber() const;
    string getName() override;
    ItemType getType() override;

private:
    int _number;
};
```

Существует класс **Cell** где содержится эти самые предметы

```
class Cell
{
public:
    Cell();
    bool Add(Item& item, int count = 0);

private:
    Item* _item;
    int _count;
};
```

Так-как класс абстрактный, то при добавлении предмета в **Cell** я могу лишь использовать методы getName(), getType(). А конкретно методы getNumber() предмета **SymCard** - нет.

Были предложения с помощью **type** узнавать какой предмет находиться в инвентаре и каждый раз кастовать для каждого предмета. Но это не удобно и думаю, что есть возможно лучше.

Как быть или же где про это можно почитать?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113275/discussion-on-question-by-----).

Answer (score 1):

Допустим возвращаемый тип методов, которые нужно вызвать _ одинаковый. Тогда для какого то типа R я просто напишу пример кода, и, если появятся вопросы, добавлю разъяснения:

```
/*Сделаем базовый класс шаблонным,
добавим do_it(), которую производные классы могут и не переопределять*/
template <class R>
class Item
{
protected:
    using type = R;
public:   
    virtual type do_it() { return R(); }
    virtual string getName() = 0;
    virtual ItemType getType() = 0;   
};

//допустим  нам нужны методы, возвращающие int
class SymCard : public Item<int>
{
    
public:
    virtual type do_it()  {       
        return  getNumber();
    }
    SymCard(int number){}
    int getNumber() const { return _number; }
    string getName() override { return "SymCard"; }
    ItemType getType() override {  }
    SymCard() : _number(1){}
private:
    int _number{};
};

class Obj : public Item<int>
{
    char c = 'a';
public:
    Obj() = default;
    virtual type do_it() {
        return  getCh();
    }
    string getName() override { return "Obj"; }
    ItemType getType() override {  }
    int getCh() const { return c; }

};
template <class R>
class Cell
{
public:
    Cell() :_item(0),  _count(0) {}
    
    bool Add(Item<R>& item, int count = 0)
    {
        ++count;
        _item = &item;
        return _item;
    }
    
    virtual void  show() const {
        std::cout << _item->do_it() << std::endl;
    }
    //...
private:
    Item<R>* _item;
    int _count;
};
int main() {
    Cell<int> c;
    SymCard s;
    Obj ob;
    c.Add(s); 
    c.show();
    c.Add(ob);
    c.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Конечно код не имеет товарный вид, но, по мне, отвечает на вопрос.
Ну как быть, если хотим, чтобы  do_it()  вызвал функции_члены с разной сигнатурой? Тут нужно импровизировать с того, что имеем...

P.S.
Исходя из комментариев автора вопроса, задача сводится к более тривиальной. Я не буду писать разные производные классы, потому что они все будут одинаковыми, потому я напишу просто шаблон производного класса. Базовому классу нужен лишь один виртуальный метод, чтобы вызвать переопределенный метод производного класса, который и выводит информацию в нужный нам поток:

```
struct Item {  
    
    virtual  void getData(std::ostream&) = 0;
    virtual ~Item() = default;
};

template <class R>
class Product  : public Item {     
public:
    R obj;
    explicit Product(const R& data) 
        : obj(data)  { }
    void getData(std::ostream& out) override
    {
        out <<"id: " << obj << '\n';
    }
};
```

Теперь, для списка товаров(в примере будет массив указателей на них) напишем простой пример:

```
int main() {
   Item* arr[] = {
        new Product<int>(5),
        new Product<std::string>("five"),
        new Product<char>('p')
    };
    //получим храниую информацию каждого объекта
    for (auto ptr : arr) {
        ptr->getData(std::cout);
        //...
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что мой вопрос был не совсем корректен и вызвал недопонимания. 

Но, если так:

Есть у нас абстрактный класс Item, от него наследуем все другие предметы (ведь так и необходимо делать, верно?)

Допустим будет существовать магазин и там будут находиться различные предметы. При просмотре их, мне необходимо получить их индивидуальную информацию (у сим-карты номер телефона, у телефона - серийный номер и т.п.). Как в таких ситуациях необходимо делать?

Comment: Ну да,  если известна цель, то можно применить разные подходы решения. Еще один вопрос:  где вы хотите хранить эту информацию, куда записывать? Вывести на консоль?

Comment: Хранить индивидуальную информацию? Непосредственно в классе с предметом. Выводить на консоль, да

Answer (score 0):

Код, вероятно, вышел натянутым и кажется есть намек на утечку памяти (мне не нравится, как я на быструю руку накатал конструктор, но ладно).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

enum {_SomeStruct, _AnotherOne};

template<int StructType>
struct Item {
    int struct_type = StructType;
    virtual string getName() = 0;
    virtual int getType() = 0; 
};


constexpr int exprType = _SomeStruct;
struct SomeStruct : Item<exprType>
{
    string getName() override { return "SomeStruct"; }
    int getType() override { return struct_type; }
    string getSpecificSome() { return "Specific"; }
};

template<class ItemType>
class Cell
{
public:
    Cell() = delete;
    Cell(ItemType* item) {
        _item.reset(item);
    }
    
    string getSpecificSome() {
        if(_item->getType() == _SomeStruct) {
            auto casted = static_cast<SomeStruct*>(_item.get());
            return casted->getSpecificSome();
        }
        else
            return "No method";
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<ItemType> _item;
    int _count;
};

int main()
{
    Cell<SomeStruct> cell(new SomeStruct);
    std::cout << cell.getSpecificSome();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Надо `#include <string>` добавить

Answer (score 0):

> при показе игроку, я должен буду указать, что у симки есть свой номер, у телефона есть своя марка. И вопрос, здесь постоянно надо будет кастовать или же можно как-то сделать практичней?

На сколько я понимаю, ячейке интерфейса всё равно, будет ли это марка мобильного телефона или номер сим карты. Тогда можно просто сделать так, чтобы `Item` возвращал список своих свойств. В самом примитивном случае это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
class PropertyData {
  std::string name;
  std::string prettyName;
  std::string desc;

public:
  friend class Property;
  PropertyData (std::string name, std::string prettyName, std::string desc)
    :name(name), prettyName(prettyName), desc(desc);
};

class Property {
  const PropertyData* d;
  std::string val;
public:
  Property(const PropertyData* d, std::variant val): d(d), val(val);
  const std::string& getName() const {return d->name;};
  const std::string& getPrettyName() const {return d->prettyName;};
  const std::string& getDescription() const {return d->desc;};
  std::string& value() {return val;} 
  const std::string& value() const {return val;} 
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------

class Item {
public:
  // ...
  virtual std::vector<Property> getPropertyList{return std::vector<Property>();}
};

class SimCard : public Item{
public: 
    
private:
    int _number;
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------

class SimCard : public Item {
  static const PropertyData numberProperty;
public: 
  // ...
    virtual std::vector<Property> getPropertyList() override;
};

const PropertyData SimCard::numberProperty{"phone_number", "Phone number", 
  "A sequence of digits assigned to a fixed-line telephone subscriber station "
  "connected to a telephone line or to a wireless electronic telephony device, "
  "such as a radio telephone or a mobile telephone, or to other devices for data "
  "transmission via the public switched telephone network (PSTN) or other public and "
  "private networks"};

std::vector<Property> SimCard::getPropertyList {
  std::vector<Property> rv;
  rv.emplace_back(&numberProperty, std::to_string(number));
  return rv;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------

class Cell {
  std::vector<Item*> items;
public:
  // ...
};

void Cell::printItem() {
  for(const Item* item: items) {
    std::cout << item->getName() << std::endl
    for (Property & prop: item->getPropertiesList()) {
      std::cout << "  " << prop.getPrettyName() << ": " << prop.value() << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```